# HTML comment tag <!-- --> Removed in CQ5

Tags: tags, aem

I'm using Rich Text Editor with MiscTools plugin to edit text in CQ%
However when I open the HTML editor and create sth like this

```
<div id="test">Test <!-- Test Comment --></div>
```

the CQ rewrites it to after switch back to HTML mode and source edit mode

```
<div id="test">Test </div>
```

Is it possible to keep HTML comment tag `<!-- -->` in the source code?

Thank you for answer my question

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking it out of the div and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

In CQ5.4-5.6.1 (not sure about latest version AEM6), the Rich Text Editor intentionally strips out all HTML comments.  The only way to stop it from doing this is to modify the product javascript source code in WhitespaceProcessor.js.  However, allowing HTML comments in this way wouldn't be recommended as it hasn't been fully tested it might cause other errors.  If you still need this feature, then you might consider contacting Adobe Customer Care to request it to be officially added to the product.